# setInterval wont work if timing is too short

Tags: javascript, css, setinterval

I have a `setInterval` function that wont execute if the increment is less than 101ms. The timing will go any number above 100ms. I want to be able to increment the function by 10ms. `offY` and `strtPos` also become undefined when the timing goes below 101ms. How do I make it work the same as it is, but instead, have it incremented by 10ms?

```js
var strtPos;
var offY;
var offX;
var hold = true;
var obj = document.getElementById('obj');

var st = function() {
  offY = obj.offsetTop;
}
var init = setInterval(function() {
  other()
}, 101);  //<-- When I change that value to below 101, it prevents the code from working

var other = function() {
  if (hold) {
    strt();
    hold = false
  };
  console.log(offY)
  console.log(strtPos)
  if (strtPos - 100 <= offY) {
    obj.style.top = (offY - 11) + "px";
  } else {
    clearInterval(init);
    hold = true;
  }
}
var strt = function() {
  strtPos = offY
}
setInterval(st, 100)
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#obj {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="obj"></div>
```

Comment: Makes me wonder though why there are two intervals. The code feels needlessly complex.

Comment: It is part of a bigger project of making a game with javascript. It might be complex and not very ideal, but I don't have the attention span to learn java or some other language that would be better for it.

Comment: I can understand that (never bothered to learn Java either ;o)), but there are some basic patterns, like the game loop, for which good Javascript examples can be found too. If you start working with different timers for different events, I'm afraid it will become a tangled mess before you got anything working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is you need to give `offY` a value that is not undefined initially, so I've rearranged the variables at the top of your code.

Originally, `offY` only gets a value after ~100ms (`setInterval(st, 100)`), and without a value that is not `undefined` the `other`function's calculations won't work. So you needed the `st` function to execute first, hence requiring a value > 100.

```js
var strtPos;
var offX;
var hold = true;
var obj = document.getElementById('obj');
var offY = obj.offsetTop;

var st = function() {
  offY = obj.offsetTop;
}
var init = setInterval(function() {
  other()
}, 10);

var other = function() {
  if (hold) {
    strt();
    hold = false
  };
  console.log(offY)
  console.log(strtPos)
  if (strtPos - 100 <= offY) {
    obj.style.top = (offY - 11) + "px";
  } else {
    clearInterval(init);
    hold = true;
  }
}
var strt = function() {
  strtPos = offY
}
setInterval(st, 100)
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#obj {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="obj"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I just called st(); once before using the setInterval so that solved my problem.